# PHP/TWIG : for loop to build HTML divs

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I come from ASP.NET MVC and the following was easy enough to do. I'm wondering how it can be done with PHP and TWIG.

I want to dynamically build a series of HTML div. A div looks like this:

```
<div class="grid_gallery-item">               
    <img src="img/gallery/gallery_grid1.jpg" alt=""/>                       
    <a href="img/gallery/gallery_grid1.jpg"></a>
 </div>
```

Ths src attribute of the image as well as the href of the hyperlink should be different for every divs. I would like to do it in a for loop, using the incrementer to change src and href paths.

One more difficulty is that I use assetic (symfony2) for my paths. So the src attribute and href attribute are actually like:

```
{{asset('img/gallery/gallery_grid1.jpg')}}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used assetic but I think you should be able to do it easily using PHP [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

```
<?php $myArray = array('1','2','3'....); //this can store full image paths also?>

<?php foreach($myArray as $item): ?>
<div class="grid_gallery-item">               
    <img src="{{asset('img/gallery/gallery_grid<?php echo $item; ?>.jpg')}}" alt=""/>                       
    <a href="{{asset('img/gallery/gallery_grid<?php echo $item; ?>.jpg')}}"></a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I hope it helps. Let me know if you need more details.

**UPDATE:**
To read each file from a directory use this:

```
<?php 
$dirname = 'dirname'; 
$directory = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__).'/../'.$dirname); //modify path to your needs 
?>

<?php foreach($directory as $file): 
         if(!$file->isDot()): ?>
   <div class="grid_gallery-item">               
        <img src="{{asset('<?php echo $dirname.'/'.$file->getFilename(); ?>')}}" alt=""/>                       
        <a href="{{asset('<?php echo $dirname.'/'.$file->getFilename(); ?>')}}"></a>
   </div>
 <?php endif;
     endforeach; ?>
```

I haven't tried this part but it should work. Just modify it to your needs.

Comment: very helpful. I will give it a go. I think there is a typo though: should it not be $item instead of $i ?

Comment: Let me understand this. Are you storing your image names in an array or you just want to increment the same image name over and over until certain value is reached?

Comment: ok, the code you wrote is a good start for me. The next step is that ideally images paths should be stored in the array indeed. Even better, I should provide a folder name on the disk so that the array is built using the images in the folder. Do you know if that's possible ? Probably I should take @punk approach and do that in the controller.

Comment: I'm going to take this as the answer, although @punk approach is good too and I'll end doing a mix of both I think. Thanks guys !

Answer (score 3):

use

```
{% for div in divs %}
    <div class="grid_gallery-item">               
        <img src="{{ div.src }}" alt=""/>                       
        <a href="{{ div.href }}"></a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and here is php code

```
    $array = array(
      array('src' => 'image here',
            'href' => 'link here'),
      array('src' => 'image here',
            'href' => 'link here'),

    );
$twig->render('page.twig', array('divs' => $array));
```

Comment: not sure I understand. Where is the html in the for loop  ?  Also, the '1' after 'gallery_grid' should come from the incrementor of the for loop.

Comment: i apologize for incomplete code i have edited my answer look around it

Comment: I think this is the best approach as the array is now built in the controller and returned with the view. I guess I need to find how to build the array dynamically from images in a source folder. I think I should open a different post for that as it's not related to original issue.

Comment: use `DirectoryIterator` to fill array at runtime (from filesystem) or from database use `PDO` or `mysqli` extension